# Libre office calc invoice

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I use Calc to do invoicing. I use one sheet per invoice and one calc file per day. I calculate total amount invoiced using formula =Sum (sheet2.B25:sheet16.B25). I generate 25 files per month x 12 month. Is there a way I can calculate total amount invoiced in a year by using some formula by parsing the files considering the total of the day is on sheet1.B25
Kindly help

Comment: How are the files named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the files are simply named "1.ods" for the first day, "2.ods" for the second day, all the way through "300.ods" (that is, 12 * 25).  On the sheet where the yearly total should go, put this in cell A1 to grab the value from the first file:

```
=INDIRECT("'file:///absolute/path/to/folder/" & ROW() & ".ods'#$Sheet1.B25")
```

If you're not sure what the path to the folder should be, press <kbd>=</kbd> from one file and then click on cell B25 in the other file.  This will insert the file's path into the formula.

Now, drag the formula from A1 down to A300 to include all the files.  Finally, sum column A:

```
=SUM(A1:A300)
```

Documentation for referencing other documents: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Referencing_a_Cell_in_Another_Document